# Intellij - Predefined types to auto-import

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there any way to "say" to Intellij that at time to auto-import `List<>` (for example) it is ALWAYS the one from `java.util` package?

It is so annoying to have to point out which `List` I'm refering to every time.

Comment: I don't think that there is a way, but if there was I wouldn't suggest you to use it. When IntelliJ can, it will try to auto-resolve potential conflicts and import directly the correct type. But if it doesn't, it's because there is space to ambiguity and you wouldn't want a software to self-assess such ambiguity for you.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ - I suspected someone would raise the point you just raised :) I'm aware of it and it would be used for very common cases like List where 99% of the time is the java.util is the desired one. In case you want to use another List implementation you must know why and from which package it comes from, for all other cases let's Intellij to auto-complete the way we decided.

Comment: I understand your frustration, I think anyone working with lists is aware of that annoying "java.awt.List" proposal. But so far it wasn't too disturbing to me, w.r.t. the advantage of not letting IntelliJ decide for me. It happens in the past that IntelliJ took initiative and I've spent days debugging to later figure out what was wrong :)